# changed label text in highstock chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

My issue is that when in highstocks , I select range selector as `All in top left corner of the widget`, and now if I hover on graph I get the box with text as `Week from Monday,July 21 2008`, can I change this to `Week ended at Sunday ,July 27 2008`. I need to change the date in label ui only not on DB level. Is it possible to these changes in highstock api.

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

rangeSelector: {
    selected: 4
},
```

sample fiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/)

Comment: Sure, just use [`series.dataGrouping.dateTimeLabelFormats`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.dataTimeLabelFormats) Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ssguwsht/

Comment: @PawełFus Thanks it worked ,  what should I write if want weekday name also ; Week ended at Sunday , july 20 2014'

Comment: See [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Highcharts.dateFormat) - `%A` is responsible for weekday.